# Random hexadecimal color

Tags: javascript, colors, hex

How to change the style.color to an hexadecimal random value with this code ?

```
hexaTable = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
    document.getElementById("button").onclick=
        function(){
            if (x==true) {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="Au revoir";
                document.getElementById("text").style.color="#" + 6 * hexaTable [Math.floor(Math.random() * hexaTable.length)];
                x=false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="Bonjour";
                x=true;
            }
        };
```

Comment: `*` is for numeric multiplication, not string replication.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

This will create random hex colors : (using recursion)

```
   console.log('#' + (function co(a) {
       return(a += [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'][~~(Math.random() * 16)]) && (a.length == 6) ? a : co(a);
})(''))
```

[image]

So :

```
document.getElementById("text").style.color='#' + (function co(a) {
           return(a += [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'][~~(Math.random() * 16)]) && (a.length == 6) ? a : co(a);
    })('');
```

http://jsbin.com/ULenuFa/3/edit

Answer (score 1):

one line solution to this would be:

```
'#'+('000000'+parseInt(Math.random()*(256*256*256-1)).toString(16)).slice(-6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will actually have to repeat hexaTable[Math.floor(Math.random() * hexaTable.length)] six times, e.g.:

```
document.getElementById("text").style.color="#" +
    hexaTable[Math.floor(Math.random() * hexaTable.length)] +
    hexaTable[Math.floor(Math.random() * hexaTable.length)] +
    hexaTable[Math.floor(Math.random() * hexaTable.length)] +
    hexaTable[Math.floor(Math.random() * hexaTable.length)] +
    hexaTable[Math.floor(Math.random() * hexaTable.length)] +
    hexaTable[Math.floor(Math.random() * hexaTable.length)];
```